# How to change the default ':' in subsection to paren ')'?

Tags: sectioning, punctuation, sections-paragraphs, ieeetran

In latex, when I write ,

```
\subsubsection*{a}
```

it produces

*a:*

but I want to write

*a)*

How should I do this.

Comment: What documentclass are you using? `\subsection*` would not usually insert punctuation after the title at all...

Comment: actually it is \subsubsection, sorry for the mistake. for \subsection it's fine. And I am using \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038371/how-to-change-the-default-in-subsection-to-paren-in-latex?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following minimal example produces what you're after, modifying the "punctuation" of [`IEEEtran`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran) from `:` to `)`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@IEEEsectpunct}{)\ \,}% Modified from {:\ \,}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection*{a}
\subsubsection*{b}
\subsubsection*{c}
​\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

You could, of course, also just use a list environment to obtain the same numbering...