# dots and textform with texorpdfstring

Tags: hyperref, ieeetran, texorpdfstring

Why there exists two weird dots here?

[image]

Also how can I converter $X_{MA}=0$ to textform for the bookmark?

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\subsubsection{ Family with \texorpdfstring{$X_\mathrm{MA}=0$}{h}}
\newpage

\vspace{11pt}
\end{document}
```

Comment: NOTE while `_\mathrm` works, it's not official LaTeX syntax. Better wrap the subscript in a layer of brace.

Comment: IEEEtran is supposed to be like that e.g. [sectioning - Remove dot at the end of subsubsection - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/580240/remove-dot-at-the-end-of-subsubsection). Just use their form. (or [sectioning - How to change the default ':' in subsection to paren ')'? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42537/how-to-change-the-default-in-subsection-to-paren))

Comment: @user202729 do you mean to use `$X_{{MA}}=0$` instead of `$X_\mathrm{MA}=0}$`? This would create italic index which I think not to be correct here as `MA` is not a variable.

Comment: @user202729 but there are two dots which looks weird?

Comment: There are no two dots, that is an italic colon.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I never saw that. Is it supposed to be an italic colon there? It looks weird to me.

Comment: try again without  the math then it will look much more natural.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer but I need to put the math there. How can I fix that?

Comment: well it is the style of the class, so try to be creative. For example add some word behind the math.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer okay, I thought it was an error instead.

Comment: It might be just for the MWE but you are skipping the `\subsection` level. This could indicate that you actually want something like an `enumerate` instead of a subsubsection. Then you would also avoid the problem with the colon. However, in that case you don't get a pdf bookmark. For the subscript: I think @user202729 meant `$X_{\mathrm{MA}}=0$`.

Answer (score 1):

The last colon of subsubsection is defined in line 5387 of `IEEEtran.cls`.

```latex
\def\@IEEEsectpunct{:\ \,}
```

As far as I know, there is no good way to express it as text if it is a mathematical formula subscript.